# Copy column from one jtable to another

Tags: java, swing, jtable, copy

I have 2 JTables, and I need to copy a specific column from Table 2 (including all the data in that column) and add it to the next free column in Table 1. Does anybody know the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultTableModel` has an `addColumn(...)` method where you can specify the column name and the data for the column.

So you just need to create an Array for the column of data. Then you iterate through all the rows in the table and copy the data to the Array. Then you can use the `addColumn(...)` method on the `DefaultTableModel` of the second `JTable`.