# Copying (some columns of) a JTable to a new JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable displayed in a frame. This table must remain unmodified for
later processing. At some point I want to show a column reduced version of this
table in a dialog. So I make a copy of the original table in creating a new
`TableModel` and `TableColumnModel`, thereby skipping the columns not needed.

Everything is fine until the dialog is set to visible. Then I run into an
endless error loop, starting with an *"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 2"*.
If 3 is the index to a table row, then it's indeed too large.
As the reduced table has only two columns, a column index of 2 would already exceed. Checking the columns with
`getColumnCount()` shows that the values are ok.
I suspect my copyTable method to be the culprit, but have no idea where the 3
index is coming from.

Instead of filling the rows of the table's model one by one, I succeeded using `DefaultTableModel.addColumn(Object columnName, Object[] columnData)` as suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676489/copy-column-from-one-jtable-to-another). Then, however, I lose the columns' width information. Hence I would still like to know my fault in the current code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class CopyTable extends JFrame {
  public static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

  public CopyTable() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JTable table= createTable();
    JScrollPane scroll= new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JButton b= new JButton("Show dialog");
    b.addActionListener(e -> createAndShowDialog(table));
    add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(table.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth()+11, 240);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  static public void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(CopyTable::new);
  }


// @param columns   Indices of columns to be copied into the new table.
  public JTable copyTable(JTable table, int... columns) {
    DefaultTableModel tblModel= new DefaultTableModel(0, columns.length);
    DefaultTableModel oldModel= (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    Object[] row= new Object[columns.length];
    int iRow= 0;
    while (iRow<oldModel.getRowCount()) {
      for (int i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
        row[i]= oldModel.getValueAt(iRow, columns[i]);
      }
      tblModel.addRow(row);
      iRow++;
    }
    DefaultTableColumnModel colModel= new DefaultTableColumnModel();
    DefaultTableColumnModel oldColModel=
                (DefaultTableColumnModel)table.getColumnModel();
    for (int i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
      colModel.addColumn(oldColModel.getColumn(columns[i]));
/*      Creating a new column didn't help.
      TableColumn tc= new TableColumn();
      tc= oldColModel.getColumn(columns[i]);
      colModel.addColumn(tc);
*/
    }
    return new JTable(tblModel, colModel);
  }


  private void createAndShowDialog(JTable table) {
    JTable tbl = copyTable(table, 0, 3); // Copy only columns 0 and 3.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ""+tbl.getModel().getRowCount()+", "+
            tbl.getModel().getColumnCount()+", "+
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(),
            "Checking row/column count",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JDialog dlg= new JDialog(this, "Reduced table", true);
    dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tbl);
    dlg.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dlg.pack();
    dlg.setVisible(true);
  }


  private JTable createTable() {
    String headers[] = {"Fruit", "Colour", "Count", "Price"};
    Object data[][] = {
        {"Apple", "Green", 6, .3},
        {"Banana", "Yellow", 3, .4},
        {"Cherry", "Red", 10, 1.1}
      };

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers) {
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class<?> returnValue;
        if (column>=0 && column<getColumnCount() && getValueAt(0,column)!=null)
          returnValue= getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        else
          returnValue= Object.class;
        return returnValue;
      }
    };
    JTable tbl= new JTable(model);
    TableColumnModel tcm= tbl.getColumnModel();
    int[] width= new int[] {60, 50, 40, 40};
    for (int i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
      tcm.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(width[i]);
      tcm.getColumn(i).setWidth(width[i]);
    }
    return tbl;
  }

}
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 2
        at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:466)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:661)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2763)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5780)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2207)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2109)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1905)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:852)
```

java 18

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to copy the TableModel (they are shareable by design) - all you need is a new TableColumnModel containing clones of the original: note that the relevant coordinate system is the *model* index.

Example:

```
TableColumnModel sourceColumnModel = sourceTable.getColumnModel();
DefaultTableColumnModel reducedColumnModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel();
for (int i = 0; i < sourceColumnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    TableColumn sourceColumn = sourceColumnModel.getColumn(i);
    int modelIndex = sourceColumn.getModelIndex();
    if (modelIndex % 2 == 0) { // replace with your condition
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(modelIndex, sourceColumn.getPreferredWidth());
        column.setHeaderValue(sourceColumn.getHeaderValue());
        reducedColumnModel.addColumn(column);
    }
}
JTable reducedTable = new JTable(sourceTable.getModel(), reducedColumnModel);
```

Comment: Thank you for your remark and code, Kleopatra. (Long time no see ;-)) But as I had written, my original table must stay unmodified. Since the user may do some changements in the reduced table, I see no other way than copying the model as well.

Comment: the original table __is__ unmodified - as is the original data model, assuming the target table and its columns are not editable :)

Comment: I just made my original table uneditable in overriding ```isCellEditable(...)```. Then your code copies uneditable columns and hence the reduced table is also uneditable  - which it shouln't.

Comment: _Then your code copies uneditable columns_ no, the code creates new columns and configures it with the relevant attributes of the original columns, so you could make them editable.  hmm .. you want the user to allow editing in the reduced table? So you may have different values in the source and copied table?

Comment: Yes. The user can make some sort of suggestion, which will be checked later by the "authorities", but he/she has no right to modify the original.

Comment: ahh .. I see .. you should consider adding that little detail to your question :)

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. It's always the same story: to oneself everything is very clear, but confering this clarity to someone else turns out to be tricky. My wife can tell you. ;-) And, yes, uneditable columns is nonsense. It's the shared model which after modification makes both tables uneditable.

Comment: *hihi .. indeed, always the same story :)) Anyway, that manual copying is error-prone, so I would try to go with creating a complete copy of the original TableModel from its dataVector and columnIdentifiers: `copiedModel = new DefaultTableModel(source.getDataVector().clone(), source.getColumnIdentifiers.clone())` (caveat: there is no getColumnIdentifiers() .. so would require a custom model that somehow allows access to them or copies itself .. )

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I know quite why you get that exception, but this is a possible problem-free alternative, involving cloning the table then removing unwanted columns. This is based on the intuitive ascending ordering of required columns. Obviously the logic could be made easier by passing an array of columns to be *removed* rather than retained.

```
    // @param columns Indices of columns to be copied into the new table.
    public JTable copyTable(JTable table, int... columns) {
        DefaultTableModel oldModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Vector<? extends Vector> data = (Vector<? extends Vector>) oldModel.getDataVector().clone();
        Vector<Object> headers = new Vector<>();
        TableColumnModel cmSource = table.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            headers.add(cmSource.getColumn(i).getIdentifier());
        }
        JTable result = new JTable(data, headers);
        TableColumnModel cmTarget = result.getColumnModel();
        Set<Integer> columnsToCopy = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = columns.length; --i >= 0;) {
            columnsToCopy.add(columns[i]);
        }
        for (int i = cmTarget.getColumnCount(); --i >= 0;) {
            if (!columnsToCopy.contains(i)) {
                cmTarget.removeColumn(cmTarget.getColumn(i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: That underscore is in there for a very specific reason. See if you can figure out what that reason is

Answer (score 0):

@g00se
Your solution works. Thank you. The only drawback is that removing columns from the `TableColumnModel` doesn't remove them from the `TableModel`. So I added the following to your code

```
        int icnt= oldModel.getRowCount();
        for (int j=0; j<icnt; j++) {
          Vector<?> vec= (Vector<?>)data.get(j);
          for (int i=columns.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            vec.removeElementAt(columns[i]);
          }
          data.setElementAt(vec, j);
        }
        ((DefaultTableModel)result.getModel()).setDataVector(data, headers);
        return result;
```

But due to lack of Generics knowledge, I cannot make the code compile. Still an idea for that?
Just copying/creating a new model would avoid any removal. So I am still curious as for my original error.
Edit
----------------------------------------------------------
Generics:
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = ...
...
Vector<Object> vec= data.get(j);
----------------------------------------------------------
Finally I got my original version to work. `colModel.addColumn(oldColModel.getColumn(columns[i]));` passes only a reference of the column. But one has to create a new instance for each column in the new table.

```
// @param columns   Indices of columns to be copied into the new table.
  public JTable copyTable(JTable table, int... columns) {
    DefaultTableModel oldModel= (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel tblModel= new DefaultTableModel(0, columns.length) {
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class<?> returnValue;
        if (column>=0 && column<getColumnCount() && getValueAt(0,column)!=null)
          returnValue= getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        else
          returnValue= Object.class;
        return returnValue;
      }
    };
    Object[] row= new Object[columns.length];
    int icnt= oldModel.getRowCount();
    for (int i=0; i<icnt; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<columns.length; j++) {
        row[j]= oldModel.getValueAt(i, columns[j]);
      }
      tblModel.addRow(row);
    }
    DefaultTableColumnModel oldColModel=
                                (DefaultTableColumnModel)table.getColumnModel();
    DefaultTableColumnModel colModel= new DefaultTableColumnModel();
    for (int i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
//    colModel.addColumn(oldColModel.getColumn(columns[i])); // Endless err loop
      TableColumn tc= oldColModel.getColumn(columns[i]);
      TableColumn tcNew= new TableColumn(i, tc.getPreferredWidth(),
                                tc.getCellRenderer(), tc.getCellEditor());
      tcNew.setHeaderValue(tc.getHeaderValue());
      colModel.addColumn(tcNew);
    }
    return new JTable(tblModel, colModel);
  }


  private void createAndShowDialog(JTable table) {
    JTable tbl = copyTable(table, 0, 1, 3); // Copy only columns 0, 1 and 3.
    JDialog dlg= new JDialog(this, "Reduced table", true);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tbl);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(
        new Dimension(tbl.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(), 80));
    dlg.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dlg.pack();
    dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    dlg.setVisible(true);
  }
```